# CKeditor , git rid of quotes so content displays as html

Tags: jsf

I am building a blog application using JSF and Primefaces. I added the CKeditor through primefaces extensions. It is correctly producing html output, however when displayed in a browser all of the html tags are displayed instead of interpreted by the browser. For example here is the some test output.

Screenshot of CkEditor output:

[image: Screenshot of CkEditor output]

Looking in developer tools the above content has quotes around it. I'm assuming if I can figure out how to get rid of the quotes it will display as html.

The JCP code to display the above

```
<h:outputText value="#{(editorBean.postMarkup)}"></h:outputText>
```

Currently only have simple getters and setters in the backing bean.

```
   public String getPostMarkup() {
        return this.postMarkup;
    }

    public void setPostMarkup(String postMarkup) {
        this.postMarkup = postMarkup;
    }
```

Ultimately I would like to store raw HTML in the database to be displayed on a blog page. How can I get rid of the quotes if that is indeed the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use escape=false on h:outputText.

Comment: There are about 1.000.000 duplicates of this on Stackoverflow, please mark the question as such